# search for matching key-value pair in an array of hashes and return true if match found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Suppose I have this array of hashes:

```
[ {"nutrient"=>"protein", "value"=>12, "calories"=>48, "unit"=>"g"},
  {"nutrient"=>"fat", "value"=>5, "calories"=>45, "unit"=>"g"},
  {"nutrient"=>"fibre", "value"=>1, "calories"=>nil, "unit"=>"g"},
  {"nutrient"=>"carbohydrates", "value"=>67, "calories"=>268, "unit"=>"g"},
  {"nutrient"=>"calcium", "value"=>42, "calories"=>nil, "unit"=>"mg"}]
```

How can I return boolean true if (nutrient value is equal to 'carbohydrates' and it's calories are equal to 268 ) and (if nutrient value is equal to 'protein' and it's calories are equal to 48)

That is, in short I want to return true for above array of hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a.count do |hash|
  (hash['nutrient'] == 'carbohydrates' && hash['calories'] == 268) || (hash['nutrient'] == 'protein' && hash['calories'] == 48)
end == 2
```

What this does, is it counts any element in the collection, that passes **EITHER** this condition:

```
hash['nutrient'] == 'carbohydrates' && hash['calories'] == 268
```

OR this one

```
hash['nutrient'] == 'protein' && hash['calories'] == 48
```

And it returns `true` if there are exactly two matches.

Comment: and what about second condition that is for protein

Comment: In same array I want to check it for 'carbohydrates' & 'protein'. Is it possible?

Comment: @HemantPatil edited the answer, even though it is a solution for specific case, not generalized

Comment: I think it's supposed to be an `and` condtion, not `or`... but otherwise good answer.

Comment: I think  SteveTurczyn  is right. If I use 'or' condition thme it will output true if either of the conditions is matched.

Comment: I wonder who has downvoted it? With `&&` it will never match the condition, because it will search for 2 values at the same key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Andrey :) You are genious :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko made a good point... for any element to be true calories as to be both 268 and 48 at the same time, which is impossible, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this:

```
a.any? {|h| h['nutrient'] == 'carbohydrates' && h['calories'] == 268} && 
a.any? {|h| h['nutrient'] == 'proteins'      && h['calories'] == 48}
# => true
```

Or as a nice finder method:

```
a = [ {"nutrient"=>"protein", "value"=>12, "calories"=>48, "unit"=>"g"}, {"nutrient"=>"fat", "value"=>5, "calories"=>45, "unit"=>"g"}, {"nutrient"=>"fibre", "value"=>1, "calories"=>nil, "unit"=>"g"}, {"nutrient"=>"carbohydrates", "value"=>67, "calories"=>268, "unit"=>"g"}, {"nutrient"=>"calcium", "value"=>42, "calories"=>nil, "unit"=>"mg"}]

def all?(array, *finders)
  finders.all? do |finder|
    array.any? { |hash| finder.all? { |k,v| hash[k] == v } }
  end
end

puts all?(
  a, 
  {'nutrient' => 'protein', 'value' => 12}, 
  {'nutrient' => 'fat', 'calories' => 45}
).inspect

puts all?(
  a, 
  {'nutrient' => 'protein', 'value' => 12},
  {'nutrient' => 'fat', 'calories' => 46}
).inspect
```

Outputs:

```
true
false
```

The method will return false if a matching hash is not found from any of the hashes inside the array.

Comment: I think you can use `finders.all? { |finder| array.any? { ... } }` to avoid the explicit returns.

Comment: @Stefan true that

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `nutrient` values are unique, you could build a `calories` hash via:

```
calories = a.each_with_object({}) { |e, h| h[e['nutrient']] = e['calories'] }
#=> {"protein"=>48, "fat"=>45, "fibre"=>nil, "carbohydrates"=>268, "calcium"=>nil}
```

And check for the values via:

```
calories['carbohydrates'] == 268 && calories['protein'] == 48
#=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

Below, `arr` is the given array of hashes (as in the example) and `target` is a second array of hashes such as the following.

```
target = [{ "nutrient"=>"carbohydrates", "calories"=>268 },
          { "nutrient"=>"protein", "calories"=>48 }]
```

We wish to determine if, for all hashes `h` in `target`, there is a hash in `arr` having the same key-value pairs as those that comprise `h`. We can do that with the following method.

**Code**

```
def all_match?(arr, target)
  target.all? { |h| arr.any? { |g| g.merge(h) == g } }
end
```

**Examples**

For the above value of `target`, we obtain

```
all_match?(arr, target)
  #=> true
```

Now let's modify `target` so there is no match in `arr`.

```
target[1]["calories"] = 50
  #=> 50
target
  #=> [{"nutrient"=>"carbohydrates", "calories"=>268},
  #    {"nutrient"=>"protein", "calories"=>50}]
all_match?(arr, target)
  #=> false
```

**Explanation**

In the second example the steps are as follows. The first element of target is passed to the block, resulting in

```
h = target[0]
  #=> {"nutrient"=>"carbohydrates", "calories"=>268}
```

and the block calculation is performed.

```
arr.any? { |g| g.merge(h) == g }
  #=> true
```

As it happens, the matching hash is

```
g = arr[3]
  #=>{"nutrient"=>"carbohydrates", "value"=>67, "calories"=>268, "unit"=>"g"},
g.merge(h) == g
  #=> true
```

What I've done is merge `h` into each hash in `arr` until/if one is found, `g`, that returns `g` unchanged by the merge. For that to happen all key-value pairs in `h` must be present in `g`.

Because `true` was returned, `all?` passes the second element of `target` to the block and the block calculation is performed.

```
h = target[1]
  #=> {"nutrient"=>"protein", "calories"=>50} 
arr.any? { |g| g.merge(h) == g }
  #=> false
```

Having found a `false`, `all?` returns `false`.

Comment: Did not test it, but I think you can use `target.all? {...}` instead of `target.map { ... }.reduce(:&)`.

Comment: @Stefan, yes, of course. Not only is that more efficient (since `all?` bails as soon as it gets a `false`), but it reads much better. Thanks. (Readers: I formerly had `map` rather than `all?` and `.reduce(:&)` at the end.)

Answer (score -1):

```
a=[ {"nutrient"=>"protein", "value"=>12, "calories"=>48, "unit"=>"g"}, {"nutrient"=>"fat", "value"=>5, "calories"=>45, "unit"=>"g"}, {"nutrient"=>"fibre", "value"=>1, "calories"=>nil, "unit"=>"g"}, {"nutrient"=>"carbohydrates", "value"=>67, "calories"=>268, "unit"=>"g"}, {"nutrient"=>"calcium", "value"=>42, "calories"=>nil, "unit"=>"mg"}]

    a.map! do |value|
      if value["nutrient"].eql?'protein' and value["calories"].eql?268
        true
      elsif  value["nutrient"].eql?'protein' and value["calories"].eql?48
        true
      else
        false
      end
    end

puts a.inspect
```

Comment: Generally, `puts` isn't useful in these cases.  It produces output on the console, but the `puts` method itself always returns `nil`.  And as you want to return an array of answers (i.e. an answer for each element in the initial array) then `map` will be more useful than `each`

Comment: Also, you want to refactor this so that it returns `true` only if both comparisons are `true`.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn  Okay, Updated the answer, but OP hasn't asked that array must be the returned value.

Comment: True, but in either case `each` isn't going to work... either `map` or `any?` ... and I would not use `map!` as that will destroy the original array.